# Generate and insert date into MySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I used following code to insert the yesterday date into my_table of MySQL database. It worked fine in WAMP and MAMP. But it doesn't work in my host. What would be the reason Please help...

```
$dt = new DateTime();

$d = date_add($dt,date_interval_create_from_date_string("-1 days"));

$date = $d->format('Y-m-d');

$import="INSERT into my_table (date) Values('$date')”;

mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Please define "Doesn't work"

Comment: where is the code of this function? `date_interval_create_from_date_string()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your host doesn't support the **DateTime()** function ...

Try with **date()** and **strtotime()** functions :

```
$today = time();
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', $today));
```

Comment: Of cause that was the problem and this works fine. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, for more informations on **strtotime()** : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

Remove `”` and use `"`

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('yesterday'));
$YesterdayDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$import="INSERT into my_table (`date`) Values('$YesterdayDate')";
                                               .....^
```

[NOTE: Use mysqli_*  OR PDO functions instead of mysql_* functions(deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect/21797193#21797193)

Comment: Thank you but here it works both the way. So this wasn't the problem.

Comment: @user3206125, Thanks to pointing. For the better practice you need to use `"`