# Php - Login.php page not working? Blank Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, authentication

I'm making a php login that will redirect you to "admin.php" when you have logged in, this is my code so far, it worked when I echoed the rows with the username and password in, but when I added in a `if` and `else` statement it just gives me a blank screen with no error or anything. Here is my code:

*NOTE: I have changed the mysql database details, but I have tested them and they all connect.*

```
  <?php
mysql_connect("mysqlserver", "myusername", "mypassword);
mysql_select_db("mydatebase");
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='$user' AND pass='$pass'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num == 0) {
echo "Incorrect UserName or Password. Please try again."; session_start();
}else{
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
header("Location: admin.php");
}
?>
<form action='login.php' method='post'>
UserName: <input type='text' name='user' /><br />
Password: <input type='password' name='password' /><br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />
</form>
<?php
 }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: I intend on securing everything up once the code actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have syntax error in

`mysql_connect("mysqlserver", "myusername", "mypassword);`

you have lack in double quote
this should be

`mysql_connect("mysqlserver", "myusername", "mypassword");`

and the way of connection must be this way

`$con = mysql_connect("mysqlserver", "myusername", "mypassword");
mysql_select_db("mydatebase",$con);`

P.S 
Stop using `mysql_connect` instead use `mysqli` or `PDO`
the reason is mysql is now [Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect)

Comment: As i said to the previous answerer, I accidentally removed that when i took my MySQL credentials out. The one that is being hosted does have that quote.

Comment: @tom see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your PHP script and error_reporting (or display_error) is turned off, and therefore you are seeing a white blank page.

This is the error: *you forgot a double quote*

```
mysql_connect("mysqlserver", "myusername", "mypassword);
-----------------------------------------------------^
```

Try this:

```
mysql_connect("mysqlserver", "myusername", "mypassword");
```

If this doesn't fix your problem, you must have an error somewhere else.

Try adding these two lines at the begining of your PHP script to find the error:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: The MySQL connect part as i said i had quickly edited to take out my details of MySQL server i accidentally removed a quote. i have added the error reporting part and i still have no errors just a blank page

Answer (score 1):

1. upgrade to mysqli_ or at least use mysql_real_escape()
2. Split the 2 files
3. Blank page means, you don't have error reporting turned on so enable it.

---

**login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='login.php' method='post'>
        UserName: <input type='text' name='user' /><br />
        Password: <input type='password' name='password' /><br />
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['submit'])){

    $con = mysql_connect("mysqlserver","username","password", "mydatebase");
    if(!$con)
    { 
       die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];


    $query = sprintf("
             SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='%s' AND pass='%s'",
                mysql_real_escape_string($user),
                mysql_real_escape_string($pass);


    $result = mysql_query($query,$con);

    if(!$result)
    {
        die('Could not execute : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }else{
        echo "Incorrect UserName or Password. Please try again.";
    }

    mysql_close($con);
}else{
    echo "missing form values";
}
```

Comment: when using that i get 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/a7516168/public_html/login.php on line 2

Comment: @tom sorry I missed closing parenthese here `if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['submit'])){` I hope you have a decent IDE because i did not test this

Comment: There were some errors ive fixed them and i get this error 'no database selected' whats gone wrong?

Comment: @tom in your code you select database after connection, mysql constructor allows you to pass the database name , like this `$con = mysql_connect("mysqlserver","username","password", "mydatebase");` please adjust the credentials

Comment: i have done that i added in the database to the end like that,$con = mysql_connect("blah.000webhost.com","blahblah_root","*******", "*******_blogdb"); i have checked the details with the hosting panel and it says they are correct.

Comment: @tom is this the first time you attempt to login? if the php is on the same server try with localhost instead of the domain name for the server address

Comment: I have fixed it by selecting the database by using mysql_select_db("mydatebase",$con);