# Why can´t i get session variable to be set?

Tags: php, session

I had already used this code 2 times, but now doesn't work and i don't know why. Below is the code from the file process_login.php. The code works fine, but when i get to admin.php can´t echo $_SESSION['USER'] and the same isn´t set. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');   
    mysql_select_db('user_db'); 

    $user=$_POST['user']; 
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$password."'";     
    $res=mysql_query($sql); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($res)>0) 
    {           
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res); 
        $_SESSION['USER']=$row['username']; 
        header("location: admin.php");                              
    }   
    else
    {   
        header("location: login.php");
    }   

?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect : you may have to edit your code a little, you shouldn't be using those mysql_* functions anymore

Comment: Did you started your session in the other file too?

Comment: **Off topic:** You should be using PDO or Mysqli instead of the old deprecated Mysql extension.

Comment: yes, i forgot to say, i started the session on the other file

Comment: where does the page take you? `admin.php` or `login.php`?

Comment: if user and pass are correct takes me to admin.php, i've done a if statement in this same file: process_login.php wich let me know that it can set the $_SESSION but only on this file, when i go to admin.php session isn't set

Comment: i've just tried mysqli configuration, still the same thing...

Comment: I am asking where the redirect takes you if it is `login.php`, then your query is probably wrong, or you're supplying a wrong username/password.

Comment: it should be `if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) ` because there should be only one person with that specific username and password combo

Comment: the redirect takes me to admin.php, where session and sql conection are started

Comment: Without the source of `admin.php` we can't really help you.

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) isn't the issue also because when i echo $_SESSION['USER'] i get the msg undefined index USER

Comment: for now the code of admin.php is only:
 <?php
 session_start(); 
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');   
        mysql_select_db('user_db'); 
 
 echo $_SESSION['USER'];
 ?>

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` is numerical data for each column, `mysql_fetch_assoc` uses the column names.

Comment: Another off topic: Looks like you store passwords in plain text in your database. Don't. Hash them with a random salt, and when comparing, re-hash the user input with a previously determined salt and compare the hashes.

Comment: @KarelKubat crypt() would be the best way to store them, or the password functions in the newer versions of php

Comment: start the  session_start(); after the db connection in both files

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysql_fetch_array` will return an array with id numbers while `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return textual representation of the columns.

```
//mysql_fetch_array()
$myarray = array(
    [0] => "BILLYBOB"
);

//mysql_fetch_assoc()
$myarray = array(
    ["USER"] => "BILLYBOB"
);
```

Comment: still get the same thing and i've used this code 2 other times successfuly, just in other webservers. im thinking is there maybe a session funtion i might have to use i se no reason for this to happen