# php Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php

I'm getting this error in server but in not in localhost,what will be the problem..?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // database server name
$dbname="*****";   // database name
$dbuser="*****";   // database user name
$dbpassword="*****"; // database password


mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Your server php version is newer than your localhost, and mysql_ functions are deprecated. Learn about MySQLi or PDO from php.manual

Comment: i have to change in  all my pages...?

Comment: yes, here is also similiar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect

Comment: @arunkumar You should have never started using mysql. Everyone warned about mysql being deprecated and you're probably one of the people that never listened

Comment: what is solution @Loko...?

Comment: @Loko hes code can be very outdated so your answer is full of assumptions +  not to mention how many outdated tutorials there is about mysql connection with php

Comment: @arunkumar Siim Kallari already gave the answer to it. Use Mysqli or PDO

Comment: @arunkumar, solution is to use mysqli_ functions or PDO class.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: @SiimKallari That's why I used **probably**. Also it's not an answer, it's a comment. The documentation even warns about MySQL.

Comment: so i have to change all pages...?

Comment: @arunkumar Wherever you use mysql functions

Comment: ok...fine thank u all

Answer (score 0):

> mysql_connect : Warning This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Anyway, you need to install the php5-mysql package.

Debian/ubuntu:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install php5-mysql
```