# opencart Error Found in my website

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

I have already transformed my Website from one server to another. Everything is working fine. When I try to open my side I found this error message

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/haratistore/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 6

My Domain is http://haratistore.com/
Please advise me ...haw can I fix this type of a error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecated: mysql\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Open `opencart/config.php` and `opencart/admin/config.php`.

Change `mysql` to `mysqli`

e.g.

```
//define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
```

Comment: Okay you can do it manually. You will have to change mysql to mysqli in your config. I can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Opencart version is older 1.5.X so there is two options here:

1) you should upgrade your OpenCart to 2.x.x

2) I have developed for older version OpenCart PDO class which you have to upload in your opencart > system > database

[Opencart-PDO](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9693-PHP-OpenCart-database-access-driver-for-MySQL-with-PDO.html)