# Error: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm getting this error from a PHP file:

```
The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
```

Here's a copy of the relevant code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbltodolist` WHERE status = 'Pending'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];

echo $total;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Is there any simple way to switch this to using mysqli to avoid the error?

Comment: This question is probably older than the earth itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Answer (score 1):

**Use mysqli in this way to avoid notice.** Because mysql is deprecated with new versions of php.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbltodolist` WHERE status = 'Pending'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];

echo $total;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why not pdo? To use mysqli he has to rewrite code, to use pdo he has to rewrite code.

Comment: @Philipp also can use pdo. but mysqli is easy if some one aware of mysql that's why m just suggest mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Use **mysqli** instead mysql. For More Information Follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797209/3420541) or this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)