# Connection to xammp Database

Tags: php

Am trying to connect to a xampp server but its not working this is my code:

```
session_start();

define('DB_NAME', 'login');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if ($link) {
    die('Failed to connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $link);
if (!$db_select) {
    die('Failed to connect:' . DBNAME . ':' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecated: mysql\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql is no longer usable.
use mysqli and it will work fine

If you want to know more about it visit https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: I have changed to msqli the connection is successful but when i try to use the connection to login i get this error: success 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\process.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\process.php on line 14
login not successful

Comment: it look like you did not use $con variable read document properly

Answer (score 0):

If you can solve the problem, try it with this sentence and you will see the error faster.

```
 <?php $servername = "localhost"; $username = "username"; $password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    } catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    } ?>
```