# Deprecated: mysql_connect() with PHP and Mysql DBconfig

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "ecdb";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('cannot connect to the server'); 
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('database selection problem');
?>
```

Error:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebEnt\dbconfig.php on line 6

How should i fix this instead of ignoring the error message

Comment: Stop using deprecated functions ... like the error message tells you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect dublicate ..please check the link