# Could not connect to MySQL in PHP

Tags: php

I have newly purchased server, on that server database connections are not working.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $server   = "server name";
    $user     = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $db       = "test";
    echo "Before";
    $con = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
    echo "After";
    if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($db, $con);
?>
```

When run this file its print **Before** text but not print **After** text.

Comment: DO not user mysql_* it is going to be deprecated..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect

Comment: which PHP version are you using ?

Comment: i am using php 7.1.2

Comment: `mysql_*` removed from php7, use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: Then use either mysqli_ or PDO to connect.

Comment: @Deep not working changed to mysqli.error not showing  and how to enable error in server

Comment: what error are you getting?? Is it connection error ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/cloud/references/dbconnect.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/cloud/references/dbconnect.php on line 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can use the following code:

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Using this you can get either deprecated or not.

FYI: The `mysql_*` functions have been removed in PHP7.x. There are two modules you can use.

The first is MySQLi, just use the code as follows:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

You can also use PDO using code :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Formatting tip: when writing names of software items such as "MySQL" or "PHP 7", it is better not to put them in `inline formatting`. The names of things are not themselves code or console I/O (there are exceptions such as talking about the `php` executable, but that doesn't apply here).