# An uncaught Exception was encountered - ERROR CONNECT DATABASE

Tags: php, database

An uncaught Exception was encountered

> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 136
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php
> Line: 109 Function: DB
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php
> Line: 65 Function: initialize
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\application\third_party\MX\Base.php Line:
> 55 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\application\third_party\MX\Base.php Line:
> 60 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\application\third_party\MX\Controller.php
> Line: 4 Function: require
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\application\third_party\MX\Modules.php
> Line: 123 Function: include_once
>
> File:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\application\modules\acesso\controllers\Acesso.php
> Line: 3 Function: spl_autoload_call
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Salab\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Comment: What version of PHP? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect

Comment: enable the module in your php.ini file

Comment: my friend get also this error.

Comment: Can you put your code in this question? So i can identify easily and give best solution.

Comment: And some browser not support mysql_connect() also try mysqli_connect().

Answer (score 1):

Could you Send the method you using to connect to the database
you could try this

```
 <?php
    //Create Connection
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    //Create Database
    $CreateDb="Create database db2";
    mysql_query($CreateDb,$con);

    //Select Database 
    mysql_Select_db("db2",$con);

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php7 you should move to mysqli as mysql was deprecated
If you are using an earlier version then it seems that the mysql extension is not installed or enabled (note that looking forward you'd better move to mysqli anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Check in your php.ini file if you have the line and it's not commented:

`extension=php_mysql.dll`