# Fetch data from same Mysql column with multiple Ids

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to Fetch data from same Mysql column with multiple Ids and assign each to a variable.

My table is like this

```
|id |credit|
+----------+
|1  |10    |
+----------+
|2  |20    |
+----------+
|3  |30    |
+----------+
```

php code is

```
$sql = "SELECT credit FROM dailycredits Where id IN ('1','2','3')";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$id1= $row[0]["credit"];
$id2= $row[1]["credit"];
$id3= $row[2]["credit"];
}
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: the problem is the code doesnt fetch the data, i think its written wrongly. when I echo the variables it says null

Comment: the datatype of the credit column is Integer

Comment: Just a note about the usage of `mysql*` functions. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4932315) where it's explained why you should prefer `mysqli*` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of case **id** column is **integer**,
then remove single quotes from following line

**change this**

```
$sql = "SELECT credit FROM dailycredits Where id IN ('1','2','3')";
```

**to**

```
$sql = "SELECT credit FROM dailycredits Where id IN (1, 2, 3)";
```

Note: Single quotes removed from **IN**

Try this...

```
$sql = "SELECT credit FROM dailycredits Where id IN (1,2,3)";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$rows = []; //empty array.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$rows[] = $row; //assigning credit to array.
}

print_r($rows);
```

Or you can now access like $rows[0], $rows[2].

Since [mysql_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797118/deprecated-mysql-connect) is deprecated in php 5.5.0, I'm strongly not recommend to use mysql_, use **mysqli_*** instead.

Comment: thats not the case. it did not help and credit column and id column are different

Comment: @LoveDroid updated.
You are selecting credit based on id column, so id column is also integer. If you pass single quote its considered as string and won't give you any results.

Comment: Yes, do you think the second part of the code is correct?

Comment: @LoveDroid you want fetch credit for specific ids by group?

Comment: I want to fetch the credit data and each credit data row gets saved in a variable. So, $id1 = 10 and $id2 = 20 and $id3 = 30

Comment: @LoveDroid check now,
You have now... $rows array, which contains all of your data.

Comment: Thank you, now fetchs the data, the only issue is it gives me array for each value, I want only the value in the row, for example, $id1 = 10

Comment: @LoveDroid add this line end of code
extract ($rows, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'id');

Now access like $id_0 $id_1 and so one.